# How To Create Anonymous Calendar in Outlook 2003

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, calendar

We use Outlook 2003 Calendar to send notices for vacations, out of office, etc. How can we implement an "anonymous" calendar so that when a notice is sent, it does not indicate to the person (in their personal outlook calendar) sending the notice that they are out of office, but rather the person in the subject line?

Comment: How can you setup an anonymous calendar when it's linked to an email address which is linked to an AD account... ??? Anonymous = Permissions ONLY

Comment: @r0ca: It's a concept, nothing to do with permissions

Comment: I assume it's a concept. Basically, it's not possible to do this because as I explain, each calandar will be linked to an AD account (Exchange Mailbox) so anywho send an email to a DL or contacts will receive a notification.

Comment: @r0ca: Thanks for NOT helping. See below answer

Comment: No problem to NOT help to a WAY UNCLEAR question... Take care buddy! I've been administering Exchange 2000 to 2007 and if I answer your question word by word, my answer still stands

Comment: @r0ca: You could be the mecca for exchange and your way of helping would still suck. Obviously someone else was able to understand. Perhaps you are the problem.

Comment: Perhaps babe... perhaps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood what you want to do but I think the person sending the notice could schedule a meeting in her personal calendar and invite who she wants to the meeting without requiring their presence so they will have the notice in their calendars too. (Not sure if this is the result you want - who is the person in the subject line?).

EDIT:
OK - I think I got it. The person sending the announcement is not the person taking vacation (or other notice). You could create an account "vacations" for example and let someone as assistant of it and send from this account (this way you can even have a global map of who is in vacations looking at the "vacations" calendar). I used to do this way for meeting rooms reservations in the past and I think this is a similar situation.

Comment: Person in the subject line aka meeting announcement subject is the person name's taking vacation. Like to so that when the announcement is sent to all required participants that it does not add it to the person sending the announcement calendar. Because then on their machine it shows them as "Out of Office" during that period when in fact they are just the sender of the announcement.

Comment: I Edited the answer